# How can we include tags in our bio?

Tags: support, tags, profile-page

The question is simple. How can we include tags in our bio?
I have seen many people's bio with tags like [matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matplotlib) and [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python). How can I do something like that?

## ImportanceOfBeingErnest's profile

[image]

## Martijn Pieters' profile

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66965/is-there-some-markup-to-post-tags

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just like [in any other context](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tags) (comments, posts):

```
[tag:your-tag]
```

Comment: funny how these tags break when clicked from Martijns MSO profile: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters

Comment: Weird. Using `[tag:...]` on Meta still supposed to link the main tag. There is the special `[meta-tag:...]` for Meta tags but for some reason the tags in the Meta bio are treated as Meta tags

Comment: in the profile the link is domain relative. They don't render a fully qualified url. I consider that a bug.

Comment: @rene [reported](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407780/6045800) :)