# Main tags in user profile become Meta tags in the user's Meta profile

Tags: bug, tags, profile-page, meta

When linking main tags in Meta with `[tag:any-tag]` in a comment or post, they are rendered as main tags into the full link:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/any-tag">any-tag</a>
```

When using tags in the user's profile, they are being rendered as a ***relative*** link:

```
<a href="/questions/tagged/any-tag">any-tag</a>
```

Which makes them become Meta tags on the user's ***Meta*** profile, instead of remaining a main tag like anywhere else on Meta (for this we have `meta-tag`).

For example, clicking on any of the tags on [Martijn Pieters's Meta profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) will get you to an inexistent Meta tag, while switching to his [Main profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) will reveal the real Main tags.

---

Discovered following [this Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407778/how-can-we-include-tags-in-our-bio).

Comment: Maybe include one example user profile where this occurs. Then we can decide if we want to fix the bug or nuke the user ...

Comment: @rene Then I shall choose the user carefully xD

Comment: I'm sure [Martijn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) appreciates Dutch humor ...